# delay in finding facebook cookie using JS + Python

Tags: python, cookies, facebook

Using a mix of GAE, Python and JS I have successfully made a application connecting to facebooks API. Only one snag: In my app - the first thing i check is if a facebook cookie exists:

```
cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, 
                                       FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 
                                       FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
if cookie:
    {render index.html}

else:
    {render login.html}
```

In my login-handler i again check for a cookie (same codestructure) to avoid having people who does have a cookie accessing this page. This works as designed.

Only problem is that when a cookie does exist, there seem to be some delay in detecting this. So, the log goes:

- cookie not found in index-handler, redirecting to login-handler
- login-handler draws login-html
- cookie found in login-handler, redirecting to index-handler
- index-handler draws index-html

This is clearly visible to end-user, the loginscreen draws and then, a second or so later, the correct indexscreen is drawn.

What can be the cause of this delay? I'm wondering if its caused if the cookie is being transferred to the server? If so, how to code around this?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie `fbsr_<application_id>` will be set only after user is authenticated on Facebook, redirected back to your application and Javascript API method `FB.init()` is executed with `cookie: true`.

```
FB.init({
    appId : '<application_id>',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    //...
```

In other words, cookie is not set immediately after user is redirected back to your application.